# Manage folder independent to branches in git

Tags: git, git-branch

My repo looks like this:

```
bin/
out/
src/
```

The whole repo is split in two branches, which manage the folders `out` and `src`. Now I'd like to have the folder `bin` static across branches, so that the newest commit will appear in either of the banches.

I already looked into `excludesfile`, but it doesn't quite do what I need.

Any suggestions in how to set it up?

An alternative would be to configure commit, so that changes in `bin` are committed to every branch in the repo.

Comment: Suggestion is to dont use branches like that. Rather ignore `out` directory in git by adding to .gitignore and  have a build tool create `out` for you and give access of the build tool to everyone who wants built project.

Comment: My `out` does **not** contain compiled binaries. Programs in `bin` will take text files from `src`, execute them and put the results in `out` ... The repo is part of a test-system.

Comment: And why do u want to maintain `out` separately when it can be generated for any state of the src and bin?

Comment: There is also a database involved, which I treat as a black box in this case. `src` contains testcases to verify that the datamodel is still able to perform requests the it's supposed to be